# Is there a way to return a pair of integers using the let construct in standard ML?

Tags: return, local, ml, let

I am trying to return a pair of sums using the let construct in sml. Every way I have tried will only return one value. I have tried creating a list by using cons (::) and then returning the list, but that gives an error as well.

```
val t = [(3,4), (4,5), (5,6)];
fun sumPairs(nil) = 0
| sumPairs((x,y)::zs) =
    let 
        val sumFirst = x + sumPairs(zs)
        val sumSecond = y + sumPairs(zs)
    in 
        (sumFirst, sumSecond) <how would I return this as a tuple or list?>

    end; 
sumPairs(t);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with `(sumFirst, sumSecond)` or with `let` specifically, but with the rest of your code.

The base case and the recursions say that `sumPairs` produces an `int`, not a pair of `int`s.
Because of this, there is a conflict when you try produce a pair.

Your base case should be `(0,0)`, not `0`, since it must be a pair.

You also need to deconstruct the result from the recursion since that produces a pair, not an integer.

Like this

```
fun sumPairs nil = (0, 0)
  | sumPairs ((x,y)::zs) =
    let
        val (sumFirst, sumSecond) = sumPairs zs
    in 
        (x + sumFirst, y + sumSecond)
    end;
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it still won’t compile ‍♂️

Comment: If I copy and paste my code, it works. I think you did something wrong.

Comment: So, you’re going to think I’m crazy....I didn’t just copy and paste your code...I completely rewrote the program when I used your answer, but when I did that I typed “val t = ([3,4], [4,5], [5,6]);” instead of “val t = [(3,4), (4,5), (5,6)];” 